# sql datetime comparing to date value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know you can convert a datetime to date onmly but what if you want to compare a datetime field to a date value...? For eg.

`$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date_time = '" . $date . "'"`

How would I go about doing this since I have the date but not the time to compare with the datetime field in the database...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE DATE(date_time) = '$date'
```